# Laravel Passport logout test returning 200 when it should be denied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to write a test for the logout procedure for Laravel Passport. But every time I run it i am receiving the error `expected 401 but got 200` which means that its not actually logging out the user.

The Logout functionality in the AuthController is as follows;

```
public function logout(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $accessToken = $request->user()->token();

    $refreshToken = DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
        ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
        ->update([
            'revoked' => true
        ]);

    $accessToken->revoke();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
}
```

This works fine, but the testing is the issue.

My test is as follows;

```
public function testUserIsLoggedOutProperly(): void
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    Passport::actingAs($user);

    $this->json('GET', 'api/user')->assertStatus(JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);
    $this->json('GET', 'api/logout')->assertStatus(JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);

    $this->json('GET', 'api/user')
        ->assertStatus(JsonResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

The last assert is actually returning a HTTP_OK (200)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. Passport is for adding OAuth authentication to apps. OAuth is stateless; you make a request with a token and the request is either authenticated or not. There’s no notion of “logging out”. If you revoke a token, it just means you won’t be able to make any more requests with that particular token.

Comment: @MartinBean ... Yes thats correct, but the api/user route is protected, so revoking the token in the test should result in a 401 for the last get request right?

Comment: Passport’s `actingAs` method mocks tokens, so you’re not actually working with a token instance: https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/3cbf7980e0e80b50b0960128966c52760c486d3a/src/Passport.php#L396-L415. You’ll probably need to create and authenticate with a real token in your test database, and test revoking that stops you from viewing protected routes.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a quick reflexion (not tested) but you should do your test with :

1. get a new token, (I think you can do that without api call)
2. call "api/logout" with token get in 1)
3. check with assertDatabaseHas function

   ```
   $response = $this->json('POST','oauth/token', [
       'form_params' => [
          'grant_type' => 'password',
          'client_id' => 'client-id',
          'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
          'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
          'password' => 'my-password',
          'scope' => '',
       ] 
   ]);
   $response->assertStatus(JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);
   $token = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];

   $this->json('POST', 'api/logout')->withHeaders([
       'Accept' => 'application/json',
       'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token  
   ])->assertStatus(JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);

   $this->assertDatabaseHas('oauth_refresh_tokens', [
     'access_token_id' => $token, 
     'revoked' => true
   ]);
   ```